# Images of firebase not showing in recycleView

Tags: android, firebase

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR2BD.png)

In the above images the last one is not appearing in the recycle View what is the reason.
My main activity code is given below and you can check what is wrong with this. All the first images are uploaded by the IOS app and are appearing in the recycle View. But when I upload the images from my phone it is not showing in the recyclceView.

```
    personPicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent chooseProfilePictureFromGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            chooseProfilePictureFromGallery.setType("image/*");
            if (chooseProfilePictureFromGallery.resolveActivity(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(chooseProfilePictureFromGallery, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        }
    });
    UButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checkValidity()==true)
                {
                    detailInfoUpload();
                }



        }
    });
}

private boolean checkValidity() {
    String name = pName.getText().toString();
    String age = pAge.getText().toString().trim();
    String contactNumber = pNumber.getText().toString().trim();
    String address = pFullAddress.getText().toString();
    if(name.isEmpty())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please give a name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    else if(age.isEmpty())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please give proper age",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    else if(contactNumber.isEmpty() || contactNumber.length()<11)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please give contact number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    else if(address.isEmpty())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please give a name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


private void showToast() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Information Uploaded Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void detailInfoUpload() {
    if (FilePathUri != null) {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
        progressDialog.show();
        String uName = pName.getText().toString().trim();
        String uAge = pAge.getText().toString();
        String uBelong = pBelong.getText().toString().trim();
        String uDC = pDisappearedCity.getText().toString().trim();
        String uDD = pDisappearedDate.getText().toString().trim();
        String uAdd = pFullAddress.getText().toString();
        String uPh = pNumber.getText().toString().trim();
        String uId = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
       databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
       String postid = databaseReference.child("missing_requests").push().getKey();
        StorageReference storageReference2 = storageReference.child(postid+ "." + GetFileExtension(FilePathUri));
        storageReference2.putFile(FilePathUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                progressDialog.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        }, 500);
                        PostMissingModel postMissingModel = new PostMissingModel(uAdd,uAge, uBelong,
                                uDD,uDC,genderT,taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri().toString(),postid,uName,statusT,uPh,uId);
                        //String ImageUploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                        Log.d("mes","we are in just above uploading method");
                        databaseReference.child("missing_requests").push().setValue(postMissingModel);
                        showToast();
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })

                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //displaying the upload progress
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) progress) + "%...");
                    }
                });

    }
    else {

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        FilePathUri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri);
            personPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
public String GetFileExtension(Uri uri) {

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri)) ;

}
```

}

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: Maybe your file type is not the same. check where you are uploading the file type should in the exact format.

Comment: Shared please check it

Answer (score 0):

use its a jpeg image so, user a library called Picasso. [link](https://github.com/square/picasso)

get dependency from that URL and add it to your Gradle file and use that code:

```
Picasso.get().load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE").into(imageView);
```

if it does not work can you please share code with us?

Comment: I checked that. There is no issue in uploading. Image is uploading successfully but not retrieving

Comment: to retrieve the image from firebase 1st store its url into realtimedatabase and then get that url from firebse with code and 3rd user Picaso to set image to ImageView of recycleView

Comment: i just want to see the code, of how you set them into recycle view

Comment: All images are retrieving to the recycle View the only last one which i uploaded is not showing. I think the recycle view is ok because first 8 images are showing in the recycle view which are uploaded by another person using IOS app

Comment: After 3 hours of continues work, solved the problem